# "Sei" in German mathematical texts

Tags: german, mathematical-language

I am a native German speaker and one year ago i wrote a mathematical text and gave it to a friend who knows nothing about maths to look for typos. I often used the following or similar formulations:

"Sei X ein Y."
"Sei V ein Vektorraum."

I thought this is good mathematical style but my friend said this is not good German. Thinking about it i had to agree and changed this formulation in my text and i still try to avoid it. I think if you use this Konjunktiv, one should keep on using the Konjunktiv also in the arguments and proofs following the definition but that seems weird to me. But it's used so obviously in German math text and i can't believe all the people make grammatical "mistakes" all the time. Can you explain me the validity of this formulation please?

Comment: Related: [Why use Konjunktiv I in mathematics?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1756/9551)

Comment: The suggested link answers your question very well. "Sei" is correct in this context.

Comment: I think this question belongs on the [German Language SE](http://german.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: During my study of math I had the same question 30 years ago and asked a Duden comittee for it. "Sei X ein Y" is in contradiction to the German verb's second position in main clauses. They suggested to use "Es sein X ein Y".